# What will happen to my code when I force quit an iOS app?

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS app. I am wondering what will happen to my code if the app is force quit. Will the current code been executed before the app is terminated or will it be stopped at once? Do I need to make my app robust enough that whenever the user force quit the app, it will never crush in future?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's interrupted instantly, but it will for sure be interrupted in no more than 5 sec. When the user force quits the app, a func named applicationWillTerminate, from your AppDelegate, is called. Take a look at its documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIApplicationDelegate method `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` will be called which gives you the opportunity to run code.

From the [applicationWillTerminate(_:) - UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) documentation:

> This method ***lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and purged from memory entirely***. You should use this method to perform any final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources, saving user data, and invalidating timers. ***Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return***. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

Your app is given an opportunity to save/cleanup before it is purged, and your method gets five seconds to run before the process is terminated by the operating system.

Comment: What if the device is turned off? It usually cost less than 5 seconds.

Comment: @CollinZhang The app isn't technically getting terminated in that case. It stays in the memory.